# Scrape data from mcqs

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to scrape data from MCQs but they will provide me an error and also want to go to `next page`
and how I go on `next pages` to scrape all the MCQs data is there any feasible solution kindly tell us

```
    import time
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    
    # options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    
    chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
        options=options
    )

def supplyvan_scraper():
    with chrome_driver as driver:
        driver.implicitly_wait(15)
        URL = 'http://www.tulsithakur.com/bankingquiztwo.php'
        driver.get(URL)
        time.sleep(3)
        
        title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='quest']//text()")
        option_1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='onee']//text()")
        option_2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='two']//text()")
        option_3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='three']//text()")
        option_4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='four']//text()")

        print(title,option_1,option_2,option_3,option_4)
    


supplyvan_scraper()
```

Comment: if you get error message then show it in question (not in comments) as text. Don't expect that we will run code to see errors. Besides code may work correctly on our computers.

Comment: it seems to go to next page you have to `click()` on `<input value="Next">`   - `xpath('//input[@value="Next"]').click()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page contains no text in MCQ questions as well as in options. And if you click on the next button only then it fetches the data but it says undefined in every field (question, answers).

you may check it like this -

```
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="next"]').click()
        
        title = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@id='quest']").text
        option_1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@id='onee']").text
        option_2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@id='two']").text
        option_3 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@id='three']").text
        option_4 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@id='four']").text

        print(title, option_1, option_2, option_3, option_4)
```

And if you want to scrape data from all pages by clicking the next button, you can try this -

```
        try:
            while True:
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="next"]').click()
    
                title = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@id='quest']").text
                option_1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@id='onee']").text
                option_2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@id='two']").text
                option_3 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@id='three']").text
                option_4 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@id='four']").text
    
                print(title, option_1, option_2, option_3, option_4)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

If you click the left-sidebar first (`Available Quiz Sets`) then the `undefined` problem will go away.

So, the ideal steps would be -

1. click on the set option ( left sidebar)
2. scrape the qs and while clicking the next button

Set option button  -

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="features-wrapper"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/section/div/ul/form[1]/div/li/input')
```

The value of `form` will be changed for each of option. For your page there are 70 options, so you may loop through each option and scrape the data

Comment: they will give me these `undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined`

Comment: that's website's (server) issue, not yours, the code is fine

Comment: so there is any solution for server

Comment: I think you have to click the left sidebar option first, then you won't get `undefined`

Comment: I updated my answer, check, it may solve your problem

Comment: ok  I  will try it

Comment: not working show these error `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="features-wrapper"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/section/div/ul/form[1]/div/li/input"}`

Comment: try different browser, edge or firefox